# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cytoolz' has no attribute 'update_signature_registry' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, cython, ethereum, nft, brownie

i'm trying to run eth-brownie on my system but I'm getting this error from cytoolz .i tried install cython,cytoolz and then eth brownie but when I trying running brownie I get this following error all the time

```
`

    File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Python310\Scripts\brownie.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from brownie.project import compile_source, run
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .main import (  # NOQA 401
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 36, in <module>
        from brownie.exceptions import (
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
        import eth_abi
      File "C:\Users\girid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\eth_abi\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from eth_abi.abi import (  # NOQA
      File "C:\Users\girid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\eth_abi\abi.py", line 1, in <module>
        from eth_abi.codec import (
      File "C:\Users\girid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\eth_abi\codec.py", line 11, in <module>
        from eth_utils import (
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
        from .

applicators import (  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\applicators.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .functional import to_dict
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\functional.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .toolz import compose as _compose
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\toolz.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cytoolz import (
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\cytoolz\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    functoolz._sigs.update_signature_registry()
  AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cytoolz' has no attribute 'update_signature_registry' (most likely due to a circular import)`
```

Can anyone please help me out?
Thank you

Comment: Is brownie pip installed or pipx?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcI1_e38BWs